# With data.table, concatenate variables into a single variable

Tags: r, data.table

Say I have the following data.table:

```
dt <- data.table(a=c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "ABC", "CBA", "BAC", "CAB", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "ABC", "CBA", "BAC", "CAB"),
                 b=c("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"))
```

which creates:

```
      a     b
 1: AAA   One
 2: BBB   Two
 3: CCC Three
 4: ABC  Four
 5: CBA  Five
 6: BAC   Six
 7: CAB   One
 8: AAA   Two
 9: BBB Three
10: CCC  Four
11: ABC  Five
12: CBA   Six
13: BAC   One
14: CAB   Two
```

What I want is a new variable, c, to concatenate whatever's in each of a, so it would look kindof like:

```
      a              c
 1: AAA     "One, Two"
 2: BBB   "Two, Three"
 3: CCC  "Three, Four"
 4: ABC   "Four, Five"
 5: CBA    "Five, Six"
 6: BAC     "Six, One"
 7: CAB     "One, Two"
```

I think I'm on the right track with something like

```
dt[, .SD[,b], by=a]
```

which returns

```
      a    V1
 1: AAA   One
 2: AAA   Two
 3: BBB   Two
 4: BBB Three
 5: CCC Three
 6: CCC  Four
 7: ABC  Four
 8: ABC  Five
 9: CBA  Five
10: CBA   Six
11: BAC   Six
12: BAC   One
13: CAB   One
14: CAB   Two
```

Any ideas?  Thank you!

Comment: You're on the right track, except your expression in `j`. Try: `dt[, list(c=paste(b, collapse=", ")), by=a]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you wanting something like this?

```
dt[,list(c=list(I(b))),by="a"]

     a          c
1: AAA    One,Two
2: BBB  Two,Three
3: CCC Three,Four
4: ABC  Four,Five
5: CBA   Five,Six
6: BAC    Six,One
7: CAB    One,Two
```

Comment: I'm not at my console right now so I'll try this in the morning, but could you explain the underlying logic here so I can better learn why this works?

Comment: I is what I'm most curious about.  I actually haven't updated R yet so I presume that bug won't affect me?

Comment: Ok, it worked like a dream.  By the way, I notice that in my actual script that I'm working on, at first it just returned a bunch of numbers instead of the strings.  This is because it was a factor.  When I converted the variable to a character, it all worked as expected.  As an FYI, why does it act so weird as a factor?